# Automatic Scrolling Suddenly Stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, timing

I've written the following script with the simple purpose of scrolling to the right when the user hovers over the right side of the screen and scrolling to the left when the user hovers over the left side of the screen. It works fine except that if you leave the mouse in the same spot for too long, then scrolling will stop before reaching the end. It begins scrolling again if you subsequently move the mouse. I can't understand why this is happening, since the code initiates an infinite timed loop which checks mouse position and scrolls accordingly. Its as if the mouse position stops being reported if the mouse is inactive for too long. Any ideas?

```
var mouseX = 0;
var scrollX = 0;
var timer;
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Record the mouse position if the mouse is moved
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
    });
    // Record the scroll position if the page is scrolled
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        scrollX = $(window).scrollLeft();
    });
    // Initiate the scrolling loop
    scroll();
});

function scroll() {
    // If the user is hovering over the right side of the window
    if ((mouseX - scrollX) > 0.75*$(window).width()) {
        scrollX += 1;
        $(window).scrollLeft(scrollX);
    }
    // If the user is hovering over the left side of the window
    if ((mouseX - scrollX) < (0.25*$(window).width())) {
        scrollX -= 1;
        $(window).scrollLeft(scrollX);
    }
    // Repeat in 5 ms
    timer = window.setTimeout('scroll()', 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what's wrong with your code, but why don't you use jQuery's animation? 
It's more reliable than writing your own.

```
//inside $(document).ready():

var which = 0;
$('body').mousemove(function(e) {
    var w_width = $(window).innerWidth();
    var prc = (e.pageX - $(window).scrollLeft())/w_width;

    var next_which = prc < 0.25 ? -1 : (prc > 0.75 ? 1 : 0);

    if (next_which == which)
        return;

    which = next_which;
    $('html,body').stop(true);
    if (which != 0)
        $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: (which > 0 ? $(document).innerWidth()-w_width : 0)}, 2000);

}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('html,body').stop(true);    
    which = 0;
});
​    ​
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/buMKR/1)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `mousemove()` event fails to fire when `e.pageX > $(window).width()` (or thereabouts). Looks like a jQuery bug to me. That could be impeding your progress!